How to check IP address and proxy performance
How to check that the proxy is working and the transaction goes through it. Because it also passes with the wrong proxy
const { JsonRpcProvider, FetchRequest } = require('ethers');
const { HttpsProxyAgent } = require('https-proxy-agent');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fetchReq = new FetchRequest('rpc');
fetchReq.agent = new 
HttpsProxyAgent('http://login:password@ip:3128');
const provider = new JsonRpcProvider(fetchReq);

provider.getBlockNumber().then(console.log);
provider.getTransactionCount("address").then(console.log);


Already found a solution. Now works only with the right proxy
const { JsonRpcProvider, FetchRequest } = require('ethers');
const { HttpsProxyAgent } = require('https-proxy-agent');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { createProxy } = require('proxy');
const http = require('node:http');
const fetchReq = new FetchRequest('rpc');

fetchReq.getUrlFunc = FetchRequest.createGetUrlFunc({ agent: new 
HttpsProxyAgent('login:pass@ip:port')}); 

const provider = new JsonRpcProvider(fetchReq);
try{

provider.getBlockNumber().then(console.log);
} catch (error){
console.error(error);
}

